# Determining whether the geometry field in a SQLite table has z coordinates using Python

Tags: python, shapely, sqlite

In the Shapely [package](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/shapely/stable/shapely.pdf), there is a function that allows you to determine whether coordinates include a Z value. It is `object.has_z`.

Is there a way that a similar command can be carried on the geometry column of a SQLite table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a SpatiaLite database you can use the SQL function ST_Is3D http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html. Example that returns "1" as a result

```
SELECT ST_Is3d(ST_GeomFromText('POINTZ (1 1 1)'));
```

CoordDimension and ST_NDims can by used as well, the first returns "XYZ" and the latter "3" but I think that ST_Is3D is the best match for you.

Comment: I tried that but I get "-1" as a results, which the link says is "for UNKNOWN corresponding to a function invocation on invalid arguments." I am calling it with this code ```conn.execute("SELECT ST_Is3d(ST_GeomFromText('a_table'));")```. Is that correct?

Comment: No, that's not correct SQL. If your table is named "my_table" and the geometry field is "geom" do `SELECT ST_Is3D(geom) FROM my_table`.